# SQL - creating date range

Tags: sql

I am using the following follow script to show me the cap_date and max_capacity in the future and ... and sub-queries to show me the last_date and last_qty where older than the first select statement.

```
select 
    trunc(gp.cap_date) cap_date, gp.max_capacity, 
    (select max(trunc(gp1.cap_date)) 
     from GPS_CAPACITY gp1 
     where gp.plant = gp1.plant 
       and gp.work_center_no = gp1.work_center_no 
       and gp1.cap_date = (select max(gp2.cap_date) 
                           from GPS_CAPACITY gp2 
                           where gp.plant = gp2.plant 
                             and gp.work_center_no = gp2.work_center_no 
                             and gp2.cap_date < gp.cap_date)) last_date,
    (select max(gp1.max_capacity) 
     from GPS_CAPACITY gp1 
     where gp.plant = gp1.plant 
       and gp.work_center_no = gp1.work_center_no 
       and gp1.cap_date = (select max(gp2.cap_date) 
                           from GPS_CAPACITY gp2 
                           where gp.plant = gp2.plant 
                             and gp.work_center_no = gp2.work_center_no 
                             and gp2.cap_date < gp.cap_date)) last_qty
from 
    GPS_CAPACITY gp
where 
    gp.plant = 'W'
    and gp.work_center_no = 'HPKG'
    and trunc(gp.cap_date) > trunc(sysdate)
```

Output from this script looks like ...

[image]

... what I would like is to do is create a date list starting from the 'last_date' and show a qty for each date equal to last_qty; once the date list reaches the 'cap_date' qty should change to the max_capacity (the dates should run 7 days after the 'cap_date', i.e.

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: A calendar table, one row per date, would come in really handy here.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: This is not very clear since you don't show what your data model is.  To really be able to help we would need your data model, input data and expected output.  Also we would need to know the platform (DB2, MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

First create a cal table containing the range of dates of interest. Lets call that table cal with one column dt of type date.  Assume your table above is called table_cap

Now do a

```
select cal.dt, case when cal.dt<cap_date then qty else max_capacity end 
from  cal
inner join table_cap on 
(table_cap.last_date <= cal.dt  
 and cal.dt < adddate(capdate, interval 7 day )
```